# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am learning MVC hence unable to figure out simpler stuff I believe. I am trying to keep both List and Create actions on the same View. As advised I created a ViewModel but it is throwing an error. I am sure there are some fixes required in my below code.

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[Entity.EmployeeVM]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Entity.EmployeeVM'.

My Model Class

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

My View Model Class

```
public class EmployeeVM
{
   public Employee Employee { get; set; }
   public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

My Repository Interface and its implementation

```
public interface IRolesRepository
{
    IQueryable<EmployeeVM> Employees { get; }
    void Save(EmployeeVM Employee);
}

public IQueryable<Test> Employees 
{
    get { return context.Employees; }
}

Similar function for Saving
```

My Controller Class

```
public ViewResult Index()
{

    return View(repository.Employees);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(EmployeeVM employee, string Name)
{
    employee.Employee.Name = Name;

    repository.Save(role);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");

}
```

My View

```
@model ERP.Domain.Entity.EmployeeVM

<div class="jumbotron">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
    {

        <label>Name</label>
        <input id="txtName" type="text" name="Name" class="btn btn-default" />


        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
    }
</div>
<div>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr>
            <th>  
              Name
            </th> 
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Roles)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Edit")
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action is returning `IEnumerable<ERP.Domain.Entity.EmployeeVM>` while in your view you have model `ERP.Domain.Entity.EmployeeVM`.

In your view change model of View:

```
@model IEnumerable<ERP.Domain.Entity.EmployeeVM>
```

or :

```
public ViewResult Index()
{

    return View(repository.Employees.ToList());
}
```

and in view:

```
@model List<ERP.Domain.Entity.EmployeeVM>
```

Comment: this is now giving me a new error, `EntityType 'EmployeeVM' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType` at this line of code - 'return View(repository.Employees.ToList());`

Comment: you have not defined key in model add a property of ID and decorate it with key attribute

Comment: hi that error got resolved...now m facing a simple error...but s scratching my head for solution

Comment: the new error is - `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Entity.Employee]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Entity.EmployeeVM]'`. i know i need to change this - `public ViewResult Index()
{

    return View(repository.Employees.ToList());
}`

Comment: error says all view has different model defined while passed object is of different type

Comment: how do i pass EmployeeVM object to the view from my controller action? please explain.